# Wordpress code Alphabetical Pagination

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, pagination

I would like to ask for help about alphabetical pagination codes for wordpress in PHP or any idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily add WordPress alphabetical pagination without touching code just install this amazing plugin of WordPress Alphabetical Pagination: https://wordpress.org/plugins/alphabetic-pagination/

i hope it help you if you need more help we are here for you

Comment: hai sir. Muhammad Waseem, thank you for giving such idea and link. I would like and wish to use the hard coded method in wordpress because it will not ask for premium version

Comment: dear just download that plugin, see it coding and same implement in your website...
if you feel difficulties to understand that plugin code let me know so i help you out